# Synchronizing data between SQLite (Android) and MS-SQL (Hosting)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, timertask, data-synchronization

I need to Synchronize some tables between the App SQLite Database an a MS SQL Database hosted online.

I already have a COLUMN (IsSync) on each table that allows me to know which ROWS are pending sync (i.e. SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE IsSync=0)

The **Locations** table is one of the tables that I need to synchronize as soon as the table got updated/inserted. This table contains GPS Location data (Lat,Lng,Accuracy,Speed, etc) that is inserted **EACH AND EVERY 3-4 SECONDS** (15 records each minute).

Since I need to keep checking every N (2,3,4,etc) SECONDS how many rows need to be SYNC... **what should I use inside my Activity... a TIMER, a SERVICE, a ???**

*IMPORTANT*

- I want to have the process of INSERTING data on this table APART of the process that CHECKS how many rows must be UPDATED (via JSON to HOST)
- The process must be Asynchronous inside my Activity in order to not interfere with any other task/thread running inside the Activity.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `SyncAdapter`:
https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

> Synchronizing data between an Android device and web servers can make your application significantly more useful and compelling for your users. For example, transferring data to a web server makes a useful backup, and transferring data from a server makes it available to the user even when the device is offline. In some cases, users may find it easier to enter and edit their data in a web interface and then have that data available on their device, or they may want to collect data over time and then upload it to a central storage area.