# How to structure local database for deleting rows when syncing from server

Tags: android, sql, json, database, sqlite

I currently have a local SQLite database that will update periodically from a server.

Initially, the local database will be empty. The app will fetch entire server database as json, and insert all the new rows locally.

After some time the app will fetch the entire server database as json again, and insert any new rows, or update any existing rows that have changed.

Now, the issue is if the server's database has removed an item (row). The app will never be aware of these removed items, and it will exist forever locally.

What's the best way to handle this?

A few ideas:

- Add a "is deleted" flag on each item. This would allow the app to remove any items, but this seems like it would be harder to maintain, and a lot of changes for each table. Although it would allow you to undelete items as well.
- Same idea as the flag, just modify as existing field and return it. For example, return a negative id ( `id = 150` -> `id = -150` ). This wouldn't require any database changes, but is confusing to anyone who doesn't know what's happening.
- Modify the result to return a list of "deleted" items. This wouldn't be too much work, but doesn't seem like a good solution either.

Is there any standard pattern to follow for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronizing data between SQLite (Android) and MS-SQL (Hosting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615361/synchronizing-data-between-sqlite-android-and-ms-sql-hosting)

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe, that question is just about synchronizing data, and they only mention inserting / updating. My question is specifically about deleting rows that are already deleted from the server / backend.

Comment: Can give a look at [source code](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Server-Synchronization-(SyncAdapter)) … I can see it includes _insert_ , _update_ , _delete_ ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Realm instead of SQLite for better experience, And When the app is fetching the data from server clear all data in the realm and insert new records, It will not save the removed item.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm using Room currently. And no, I don't want to clear the tables, that would be very expensive.

Comment: Then create a column for delete_status. and change that if the row is removed.